# How to filter association entities across a mapping table using Spring Data JPA(Hibernate)?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, soft-delete

Is there a way to filter a soft deleted many-to-many association using `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne`, across an intermediate entity(mapping table)?

`product` and `product_option_group` are in N:M relation. I'm implementing the soft deletion using the `disabled_datetime` column and want to filter a collection of `ProductOptionGroup` from the `Product` entity. [This post](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-filter-entities-mapped-association/) is using `@ManyToMany` and `@Where` to achieve this. I followed and it worked(disabled `product_option_group`s are filtered from `product.getProductOptionGroups()`). Note `@Where` on `ProductOptionGroup` class.

```
// `product` <-> `product-product_option_group` <-> `product_option_group`

@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product implements Serializable {
    ...

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "product-product_option_group",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_option_group_id"))
    private final Set<ProductOptionGroup> productOptionGroups = new HashSet<>();

    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "product_option_group")
@Where(clause = "disabled_datetime is null")
public class ProductOptionGroup implements Serializable {
    ...

    @Column(name = "disabled_datetime")
    private ZonedDateTime disabledDatetime;

    ...
}
```

but I want to use `@OneToMany` towards the `product-product_option_group` table, like this.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product implements Serializable {
    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id.product")
    private final Set<ProductProductOptionGroup> productProductOptionGroups = new HashSet<>();

    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "`product-product_option_group`")
public class ProductProductOptionGroup implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private final ProductProductOptionGroupId id = new ProductProductOptionGroupId();

    ...
}

@Embeddable
public class ProductProductOptionGroupId implements Serializable {
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Product product;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_option_group_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @Where(clause = "disabled_datetime is null")
    private ProductOptionGroup productOptionGroup;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "product_option_group")
@Where(clause = "disabled_datetime is null")
public class ProductOptionGroup implements Serializable {
    ...
}
```

But then the `@Where` annotations won't work anymore, so disabled `product_option_group`s are also selected from `product.getProductProductOptionGroups().stream().map(o -> o.getId().getProductOptionGroup().collect(Collectors.toList())`. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add workarounds while waiting for answers.

First, I can add a view as a filter.

```
CREATE VIEW `product-product_option_group-enabled` AS
SELECT *
FROM `product-product_option_group` ppog
JOIN product_option_group pog ON ppog.product_option_group_id = pog.id
    AND pog.disabled_datetime IS NULL;
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "`product-product_option_group-enabled`") // using the view as a filter
public class ProductProductOptionGroupEnabled implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private final ProductProductOptionGroupId id = new ProductProductOptionGroupId();

    ...
}
```

Then using `ProductProductOptionGroupEnabled` for reading and `ProductProductOptionGroup` for any data modification might solve the problem. I don't like this.

- Multiple collections of an entity. Have to be careful when modifying it.
- 2 different entities on the same table. Orchestrating these might be hard(`equals()` and `hashCode()`).
- Adds a view. Better be careful when the schema is being changed.

Maybe I can utilize [Updatable and Insertable Views](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-updatability.html), but I would still need `ProductProductOptionGroup` for selecting every row.

---

Second, I can filter the collection from Java.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product implements Serializable {
    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id.product")
    private final Set<ProductProductOptionGroup> productProductOptionGroups = new HashSet<>();

    public Set<ProductProductOptionGroup> getProductProductOptionGroups() {
        return productProductOptionGroups.stream()
                .filter(o -> o.getId().getProductOptionGroup().getDisabledDatetime() == null)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }

    public Set<ProductProductOptionGroup> getProductProductOptionGroupsAll() {
        return productProductOptionGroups;
    }
    
    ...
}
```

Then use `getProductProductOptionGroups()` to get a filtered collection. I don't like this either.

- It'll select every row from `product-product_option_group` table regardless of `disabled_datetime`.
- Creates another collection. Have to be careful when modifying it.
- `javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find with id xxx` might happen. It can be solved by `join fetch`ing the trobling entity

Answer (score -1):

The WHERE clause adds filtering capabilities to the FROM-SELECT structure. It is essential in any JPQL query that you retrieve selective objects from the database. in my opinion, you should check the correct implementation of @where see the following [reference](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/where).

Comment: I'm using `org.hibernate.annotations.Where` for the `@Where` annotation. I couldn't find any other implementation. What's is the correct implementation of `@Where`?

Comment: Sadly, `org.hibernate.annotations.Where` only accepts SQL, not JPQL.